# I'm using shared prefrences to store a Location value received from gps, How can i retrive the same from the getAppData()?

Tags: java, android, gps, sharedpreferences

```
public class StorageHelper {


public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LOCATION_DATA";

public static void saveAppData(Context ctx, String key, Location value){
    SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    String lat =Double.toString(value.getLatitude());
    String lon=Double.toString(value.getLongitude());
    Set location = new HashSet();
    location.add(lat);
    location.add(lon);
    editor.putStringSet(key,location);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String getAppData(Context ctx, String key){
    SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);



    return settings.getStringSet(key,);
}

}
```

what is the second argument to pass in the `return settings.getStringSet()`?
I am expected to send a `java.lang` parameter , but a `Set` is of `java.utiity` type.

Comment: Have you tried reading official documentation?

Answer (score 0):

As said in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), second parameter is value that returns if there is no object associated with used `key` value. You can use empty set or `null`, but after call this method you should check for not null value.

Comment: Using null throws an error ( Incompatible type). it needs java.lang.String and not java.util.Set<java.lang.String>.

Comment: Using " " as the second parameter also throws an error. I may have to use getString()

Comment: Of course it needs to return `String` values, because your `getAppData` function created as `String`. Change your function type to `Set<String>`.